Entity Reference field link doesn't respect the current site language
I have content type Text with Entity reference field field_song, that links to content of type Song.
Content type Song has default language French.
When I display the field_song and check the option Link to the referenced entity, the resulting link is always /fr/node/[nid]. I want it to respect the current site language - if the current site language is English, I want the link to be /node/[nid] (English is default site language). How can I do that? The content (Song nodes) is not being translated to other languages, only the user interface is in three languages.
I even tried to create custom FieldFormatter that would create links with current site language, but it seems like something is overriding the formatter and the resulting links are always French.

Just to give you another perspective: If I had a node which was French, with no English translation, linked to from an EN page, and clicking that link didn't take me to the French site, I'd consider that a very weird bug. This is kind of the whole point of translation; if you want that node to be on the English site, you need an English translation
